# How to make local application accessible for other pc in my local network

Tags: windows, networking, port, hosting, lan

I would like to host an application from a local Windows pc, for my local network

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application (currently running in debug mode) on Windows pc A (192.168.1.10) on port 5001

There is another Windows pc B (192.168.1.11) that would like to access the application that pc A is hosting

When i disable the firewall on pc A, I am able to ping pc A from pc B, but I am unable to browse the web application hosted on port 5001 (https://192.168.18.10:5001)

There is no active CORS policy on the hosted application

Are there any steps that i've overlooked? Do you have any thoughts on how I could resolve this issue?

UPDATE: I have now installed NGINX as a reverse proxy and this seems to work.
Is there any information on why I could not achieve this without NGINX?